# How to add headings in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

There seems to a method called subtract headings in Netlogo but method called add headings? For example :if I wish to add 340 and 25. Is there a available command to achieve this?

Comment: Depends on what you want that mean. What does it mean to add north and south, or to add northeast and southeast? What answer do you expect?

Comment: It is linked  to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401242/rotating-a-turtle-through-cone-of-vision. I was trying to use this to calculate the upper-limit rotating to end of cone of vision.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add an angle to a heading, rather than add two headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to rotate right by 25 degrees from 340, you could simply use mod arithmetic to bring the total back to a heading range. See my answer to your related question [Rotating a turtle through cone of vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401242/rotating-a-turtle-through-cone-of-vision) for what you really want.

```
set heading (340 + 25) mod 360
```

Comment: This is the right way to do the calculation. But note that `set heading` does `mod 360` itself, so if the answer is only going to be used with `set heading`, it isn't necessary to use `mod` at all.